# How can I test my Blackberry application?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

This is just AWFUL! It takes me much to long to create my Blackberry application. I'm not even coding it yet just creating the GUI!

I have code the UI using Java code, then run it, then wait for it to package and launch, then I can see the changes.

Imagine trying to position elements. It takes much too long!

Is there a better way to design a UI in Blackberry? I think I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 5.0 higher JDE (or Eclipse plugin) as well as a simulator running 5.0 or higher, they have the option to reload your application ("hot swap") without having to restart the simulator.  This is ideal for tweaking UI code.  See http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-To-Use-Hot-Swap-with-the-BlackBerry-Simulator/ta-p/526065 for details.

Comment: Do you mean while having the UI open, right clicking inside the Eclipse code and selecting Run As > Blackberry? That's what I do now and it's really really slow. I must waste around 20 minutes each day waiting for it to load.

Comment: Are you using "debug"?  http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/04/new-code-hot-swap-feature/

Answer (score 0):

If you are a new developer, it may do you a lot of good to develop for Blackberry devices having OS 4.5 as the emulator that comes with 4.5 is quite faster to load. However when you start testing for OS' above you could take advantage of the Hot swap to make reloading of applications faster.